# windows 8 store Application , Using Rijndael Encryption & Decryption

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I am trying to decrypt a string using Rijndael algorithm.
But I could not use System.security.cryptography .Is raises "Error
1
The type or namespace name 'Cryptography' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on your project

Check Target Framework, it should be **.NET Framework 4.5**
and *not* **.NET Framework 4.5 Client Profile**

Comment: Search for System.Security.dll on your pc, you should find different versions of it, copy the proper version in a proper place and add reference to it and check if it works

Comment: Thanks for the Quick reply.I tries that option too.But still I could not import Rijndael class in the coding part.

Answer (score 1):

Know this is an old question, but Windows 8 Store apps use a subset of .NET, '.NET For Windows Store Apps', which means that some libraries have not been ported. You will need to use Windows.Security.Cryptography instead, and refactor to use those libraries instead.